# "Unexpected Token" when using the map function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learning React and the idea of state and props is fairly new. At the moment I'm trying to create a SideNav component that renders some SideNavButton components. It's my first attempt at trying to pass props to child components and I keep getting this really unhelpful error that looks like this:

```
Syntax error: ./components/side-nav.js: Unexpected token, expected , (43:8)
41 |           <SideNavButton button={button} />
42 |         );
>43|       });
.. |         ^
44 |     );
45 |   }
46 |
```

I've honestly come to believe that this isn't even pointing at the problem. I'll post my code, and feel free to let me know if there is anything I could be doing better.

*./index.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import SideNav from './components/side-nav';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SideNav />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

*./components/side-nav.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SideNavButton from './side-nav-button';


class SideNav extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      navButtons: [
        {
          label: "Profile",
          icon: "fas fa-user",
          location: "#!"
        }, {
          label: "Experience",
          icon: "fas fa-book",
          location: "#!"
        }, {
          label: "Education",
          icon: "fas fa-university",
          location: "#!"
        }, {
          label: "Technology",
          icon: "fas fa-code",
          location: "#!"
        }, {
          label: "Connect",
          icon: "fas fa-share-alt",
          location: "#!"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  renderButtons() {
    return(
      this.state.navButtons.map(button => {
        return(
          <SideNavButton button={button} />
        );
      });
    );
  }

  render(
    return (
      <ul className="side-nav">
        {renderButtons();}
      </ul>
    );
  );
}

export default SideNav;
```

*./components/side-nav-button.js*

```
import React from 'react';

const SideNavButton = ({button}) =>  {

  return(
    <li key={button.label}>
      <a href={button.location}>
        <i className={button.icon}></i>{button.label}
      </a>
    </li>
  );
}

export default SideNavButton;
```

Comment: Shouldn't those files have the `.jsx` extension?

Comment: Should they? I'm using the create-react-app method and have no idea about webpack or babel. I could be wrong, but from what I've seen its just `.js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some issues with side-nav.js, please try this corrected snippet

```
class SideNav extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          navButtons: [
            {
              label: "Profile",
              icon: "fas fa-user",
              location: "#!"
            },
            {
              label: "Experience",
              icon: "fas fa-book",
              location: "#!"
            },
            {
              label: "Education",
              icon: "fas fa-university",
              location: "#!"
            },
            {
              label: "Technology",
              icon: "fas fa-code",
              location: "#!"
            },
            {
              label: "Connect",
              icon: "fas fa-share-alt",
              location: "#!"
            }
          ]
        };
       }

      renderButtons() {
        return this.state.navButtons.map(button => {
          return <SideNavButton button={button} />;
        });
      }

      render() {
        return <ul className="side-nav">{this.renderButtons()}</ul>;
      }
    }

    export default SideNav;
```

i have corrected the **renderButtons()** and the **render(){}** methods

Please find you code in [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/941o58mk4p)

Comment: Thank you so much! What exactly was I doing wrong if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @TylerB 1. Render method is a function that return jsx not a function call. You where doing `render(return <ul></ul>);` which has to be `render(){ return<ul>button</ul>;}`  when calling a function within the class use `this.renderButtons()`

Comment: 2.There was syntax mistakes in `renderButtons()` method

Answer (score 1):

Please read this `class` definition reference with examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Method definitions do not have a semicolon. So remove all of those.

Classes do not have consts. Consts can be in methods/functions, but can't be top-level in a class.

You could turn `const buttons = ...` into a method: `buttons() { return ...; }`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'm still currently getting the same error,  but I've updated the code in the question to reflect what you've said.

Comment: @TylerB The current version of your code still doesn't fix everything described in this answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The error section? Just fixed that up now

Comment: Remove the semicolon from `{renderButtons();}`. What is the error you're getting now?